# Is it Possible to Run Java Bluetooth Adapter Functionality on React native Application for Android? if yes then how?

Tags: java, react-native

Is it Possible to Run Java Bluetooth Adapter Functionality on React native Application for Android? if yes then how?

I am Not getting Any idea that how can i create an environment to Run JAVA Application on React I searched for multile solutions but nothing worked properly.